# Odoo module A depends of module B which depends of module A

Tags: python-2.7, dependencies, odoo

I'd like to know if their is any way to make a module A depend of module B if module B depend of module A? Like having them installed at the same time? When I try, both are not selectionnable in module list.

If not, is it possible to merge both module easily?

I have to add something which imply to do this inter-dependency. Will I have to rewrite every line of both modules in a single one? I would be surprised since using different module make the development easier and more structured, odoo seams to be aware of it, so that's why I come to ask you this question even if I found nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you:

The `auto_install` flag means that the module will be automatically installed as soon as all its dependencies are satisfied. It can be set in the `__openerp__.py` file. Its default value is False.

Add this flag to both modules.

So you can create a dummy module C. Add it as a dependency of A and B. All the rest of dependencies of A and B should be in C. Then, if you install C, both modules are installed at the same time.

Comment: I'll try as soon as I end my module. But if module A and B depends of each other, dependencies will never really be satisfied, you think it will install them anyway?